# Does this relation hold?

Tags: probability

$$p(A|C) \stackrel{?}{=} \sum\limits_B p(A|B)p(B|C)$$

I tried some algebraic manipulations but couldn't verify if this indeed was true. So, does this hold or is this wrong?

Comment: How do you define the summation over B?  Regardless of how you defibe it is not true.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In general this is not true, you are probably working with a graphical model that posits some independencies among variables. For instance, the equality is true if $A \perp C|B$. Then, $p(A|C) = \sum_{B}p(A|B, C) p(B|C) = \sum_{B}p(A|B) p(B|C)$, where the first equality is just the law of total probability and the second equality is true if $A \perp C|B$.

Comment: I indeed am working with a graphical model. Thanks!